# Is adapter.js in sails.js present by default?

Tags: sails.js

First of all sorry. i know this would be a silly question, but i am very confused. and need an answer.

**Question**

I am making a project in sails.js.After running the "sails new myNewProject" command  when i looked into the  default modules  that are formed  i could not find the api/adapter in it.
so, i would like to know whether this adapter is created automatically or we will have to create it manually??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `api/adapters` directory is not created by default on new projects.

If you need to build a custom adapter, you can start with `sails generate adapter myAdapterName`, which will create the `api/adapters` folder for you along with boilerplate files for the new adapter under `api/adapters/myAdapterName`.

If you're just looking to use one of the existing adapters like `sails-mysql`, you don't need the `api/adapters` folder at all.  Just use `npm` to install it in your project:

```
npm install sails-mysql
```

A list of more available adapters is [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails#compatibility).